# Algorithm name to chain up tuples

Tags: python, algorithm

Given the following list of python tuples,

```
results = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (8, 1)]
```

which is the algorithm that produces the following dictionary?

```
{1:[2,3,4,7,8], 5:[6]}
```

That is, all related elements are grouped together with their first key occurence?

I'm trying to solve it from scratch, but perhaps there is a more pythonic way?

```
matches = {}
for r in results:
    #sort tuple
    t = (r[1], r[0]) if r[1] < r[0] else r
    lst = matches.get(t[0],[])
    if lst != []:
        #key is found. append value and dictionary. 
        lst.append(t[1])
        matches.update({t[0]:lst})
    else:
        #key not found, but maybe it's in the values of an existing entry.
        if t[1] in matches.values():
            # get the key that the value is in
            key = list(matches.keys())[list(matches.values()).index(t[1])][0]
            lst = matches.get(t[0],[])
            lst.add(t[1])
            matches.update({t[0]:lst})
        else:
            lst = matches.get(t[0],[])
            lst.append(t[1])
            matches.update({t[0]:t[1]})
```

EDIT:

This could be solved by creating an adjacency list, and then applying DFS.
For python this is via the networkx library calling the dfs_preorder_nodes method.
More info here:
https://likegeeks.com/depth-first-search-in-python/#Implementing_Depth_First_Searcha_non-recursive_approach

Comment: No that will not work. What if the second element is a key? Or the first element is part of the values belonging to a key already?

Comment: I don't understand how 3, 7, 8 end up in the first list. Except if you are asking about *connected components* of a graph?

Comment: they are related by transitive property, that is, because 1 -> 2 and 2 -> 3 so 1 -> 3

Comment: @dirtyw0lf ah, sorry, I totally misunderstood

Comment: No worries! I had the same reflex at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is *traversal algorithm*. If list of tuples is interpreted as graph edges, then we can use a graph traversal algorithm, either depth-first or breadth-first, to find the connected components.

Assuming your graph is directed use *Tarjan algorithm* for greater efficiency
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tarjan-algorithm-find-strongly-connected-components/

For undirected graphs read here.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/

Most algorithms work graph representation in form of an adjacency list.
To apply them directly, build the adjacency lists from the list of edges, and apply a the traversal algorithm. Read more about adjacency lists at geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations

Comment: Yes I was thinking along the lines of a directed acyclic graph or traversal, which would you recommend for the case that its a tuple? These I can do with singular values but I don't know how with tuples

Comment: Each tuple (pair) is a graph edge.

Comment: From the list of edges, if it makes things easier for you, build the adjacency lists, and apply more common version of the traversal algorithm. Read more about graph at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/

Comment: and this would work for the (5,6) even if its all on it's own?

Comment: sure, it should work, unless your implementation is buggy

Comment: yup. Found the python lib to do this as well. thanks.